# Morris JS chart goals labels

Tags: javascript, linechart, morris.js

How to label goal lines on a Morris Chart?

I have tried the following but it does not display.

```
goals: [10,50],
goalLabels: ['50', '10'],
```

A label on hover or a text next to the goal line could also work for me.

Comment: It seems goal lines do not have labels. You can right click on a line and inspect to see if it is reachable with css. Then have something like `.morris-goal-line:hover + .goal-label { opacity: 1; }` where goal-label is a javascript generated div with `opacity: 0;`